# Getting OS X's "Cmd + ~" functionality in Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, alt-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac-like alt-tab replacement for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/143723/mac-like-alt-tab-replacement-for-windows-7)

Is it possible to get OS X's functionality of "Cmd + ~" to work in Windows?
For those that don't know, in OS X "Cmd + tab" switches running programs but "Cmd + ~" switches windows within the current program.

Comment: Linked topic doesn't sound like it, but it actually also discusses cycling through an application's windows.

Comment: I would say that it is a duplicate of that question and according to that question...I'm not going to find a viable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure [Switcher](http://insentient.net/) to do this.

In Switcher's options, go to the Shortcuts section and click the Edit Shortcuts button.

In the Filter section, scroll down and select "Show Application Only."  Add a new keyboard shortcut for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.  Make sure you check Global shortcut.  Select Activate when shortcut is Pressed and check End session when shortcut is released.

Now scroll down to Next Window in the Window section.  Add a new keyboard shortcut for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (*not* global).  Hit OK.  You should now be able to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to bring up Switcher showing only the windows of the foreground application, press <kbd>`</kbd> to cycle to the next window, and release <kbd>Alt</kbd> to switch to that window.

Comment: It's not very smooth compared to OS X but it works!

Answer (score 2):

[NTWind's VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html) will give you exactly what you're looking for -- see the [Instance Switcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html#instance-switcher) feature.

Answer (score 1):

You want Ctrl-Tab, I'm thinking.

Comment: Nope, not relevant, only works for switching Tabs within an App, but not Windows within an App.

Comment: I tried it in an MDI-window app before I posted. It worked.

Comment: It does work in an MDI-window app like Firefox that has tabs, but if you have multiple Firefox windows open (not tabs) it won't move between them.

Comment: Because Alt-Tab moves between top-level windows, and Ctrl-Tab moves between child windows.