# Cycle through programs, not windows

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

I'm a OSX user who have to work with Windows7 based computers through work. I find the regular Windows `alt + tab` cycling quite messy when I have a lot of windows open. I wonder, is it possible to have Windows just cycle through *applications* in an OSX manner, showing the last active window in the application?

Edit: What I want to achieve, preferably without installing any additional software (very restrictive company policies) is to cycle through the applications, not the open windows. I.e. I may have eight different PDFs open in Acrobat, but I want to just see Acrobat when cycling, not all the eight windows.

Edit2: Kind of the same way as you only see Chrome when cycling, you don't see your 263 open tabs as individual "cycling choices" :p

Comment: This questions seems to me to be a duplicate of [an old question](http://superuser.com/questions/143723/mac-like-alt-tab-replacement-for-windows-7).. which is a community wiki and still unanswered. The only difference is that this question specifies "without additional software", but the other question would get a such answer it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Windows Key + Tab`. That should work.

Comment: It's still cycling through all open windows, not the specific applications.

Comment: You have not specified about the specific applications requirement in the original question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question right, but I've tried to elaborate my request.

Comment: Please can you post a screenshot of what you do in OSX?

Comment: Yeah, when I come home :-)